# Definition of list is confusing

Tags: bash, pipe

In the GNU bash manual, a list is defined as

> A list[1](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists) is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of the operators ‘;’, ‘&’, ‘&&’, or ‘||’, and optionally terminated by one of ‘;’, ‘&’, or a newline.

This definition of list is confusing me, when I replace the word pipelines in the definition, it makes more sense to me. I am not able to comprehend how a sequence of Pipelines[2](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#Pipelines) can be separated by the operators ';', '&', '&&', or '||'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Bash man page can often be confusing regarding the terms used there. But your question becomes clear(er) if you read the definition of *pipeline*:

> A pipeline is a sequence of one or more commands separated by one of the control operators `|` or `|&`.  The format for a pipeline is:
>
> ```
> [time [-p]] [ ! ] command [ [|⎪|&] command2 ... ]
> ```

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#SHELL_GRAMMAR

In short, a *pipeline* is either one command with all its parameters, or multiple of them **piped** into each other. You can combine multiple of these *pipelines* by the mentioned operators for subsequent (conditional) execution.

Comment: Oh yes, I made a very silly mistake of thinking pipelines should have at least two commands, thank you for pointing it out. This solves my dilemma, a pipeline could be a single command too, I feel so silly.